# Изменить прозрачность изображения

Tags: php, изображения

Здравствуйте!
Пишу скрипт, который будет накладывать на изображение png рамку.

Вот пример:

[image: Imgur]

А вот  сам код:

```
<?
include_once ('../header.php');
$form=$_POST['examle_src'];
$posX1=$_POST['posX1'];
$posY1=$_POST['posY1'];
$res = imageCreateFromPng('../form/2.png');
$prop= getimagesize ('../form/2.png');
$newWidthFrame=$_POST['example_width'];
$newHeightFrame=$_POST['example_height'];
$newWidth= $_POST['img_width'];
$newHeight= $_POST['img_height'];

/*Изменяем  размеры накладываемого изображения + заливаем форму нужным цветом*/
$tmp = imageCreateTrueColor($newWidth, $newHeight);
imagefilledrectangle($tmp, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, imagecolorallocate($tmp, 0, 0, 0));
imageAlphaBlending($tmp, false);
imageSaveAlpha($tmp, true);
imageCopyResampled($tmp, $res, $posX1, $posY1, 0, 0, $newWidthFrame, $newHeightFrame, $prop[0], $prop[1]);

/*Изменение прозрачности не работает*/
$alpha = 87;//Уровень прозрачности
ImageColorAllocateAlpha($tmp, 0, 0, 0, $alpha);



$im=imageCreateFromJpeg('../'.$_SESSION['img']);
imageCopyResampled($im, $tmp, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
$_SESSION['img']=$im;
?>
```

Не получается изменить прозрачность. Где ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

```
$im=imageCreateFromJpeg('../'.$_SESSION['img']);
```

Создаете Jpeg, у него нет прозрачности

Comment: Верно. Только $im - это основное изображение. А на него я накладываю $tmp - это png, именно у него я и задаю прозрачность. 
/*Изменение прозрачности не работает*/
$alpha = 87;//Уровень прозрачности
ImageColorAllocateAlpha($tmp, 0, 0, 0, $alpha);

Comment: что получается , если выводите только $tmp ? Вы проверяли?

Comment: Проверял. Прозрачность прежней остаётся.
Да, я забыл уточнить, png изображение имеет прозрачные элементы изначально. Знаю что при работе с частично прозрачными png фаилами куча мороки. Ибо надо дополнительно прописывать, что изображение прозрачное 

imageAlphaBlending($tmp, false);

imageSaveAlpha($tmp, true);

Поэтому у меня все подозрения именно на то, что изображение имеет прозрачные элементу и мне надо дополнительно что-то прописывать. Только вот не знаю что)